# Enable remove contact and view contact card in list manager (sitecore 10.2)

Tags: sitecore-forms, list-manager, custom-field

I'm extending the `IServicesConfigurator` in order to create custom fields in the list manager contact following :

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--extending-the-list-manager-to-show-custom-columns-in-a-contact-list.html

This is the result:

[image]

The problem is the following:

I can't use the removed contact and the view contact action. There is a way to maintain those options or a way to recreate them?

Thanks, Guys!!

Comment: you will need to select any particular contact and then remove contact option will enable.

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly i can't select any row in this table. Maybe `serviceCollection.Remove(serviceToRemove); ` has removed also those functionalities?

Comment: Solved:
in `ContactDataModelWithPhoneNumber` i had added 
        `public string Id { get; internal set; }` for this reason it does'nt work!!
Thanks :)

Comment: Add this as an answer, so that in the future anyone who faces this issue, can find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**:

In `ContactDataModelWithPhoneNumber` I had added:

```
public string Id { get; internal set; }
```

I was redefining the field which was already defined in the parent class.
for this reason, it doesn't work!! Thanks :)